Reproducibility of the Asymptotics of ODEs
My question has its origin and is related to this problem in heat conduction but is more general in scope.
Let $\mathbf {f(x, u)}$ be a sufficiently smooth function of variables $\mathbf x \in \mathcal D_x \subset \mathbb R^n$ and $\mathbf u \in \mathcal D_u \subset \mathbb R^m$ such that

$\mathbf {f(0, 0) =0}$;
for a given fixed vector $\mathbf u=\mathbf u \in \mathcal D_u$ the equation $\mathbf {f(x, a)}=0$ is solved by $\mathbf {x =x_a}\in \mathcal D_x.$

Define a positive causal monotonic smooth function $p(t)$ as follows $p(t) = 0 \text{ for } t<0$ and $p(t) =1 \text{ for } t>\tau_0 \ge 0$ for some fixed risetime $\tau_0$. If using the Heaviside step function then $\tau_0 = 0.$
Now consider the following autonomous differential equation:
$$ \dot {\mathbf {x}} = \mathbf {f(x, u)} \tag{1}$$
where the excitation vector is defined as
$$ \mathbf {u} = [a_1p(t-\theta_1), a_2p(t-\theta_2),..., a_mp(t-\theta_m)] \tag{2}.$$
And, finally let us also assume that Eq. 1 has a solution for arbitrary amplitude vector $\mathbf a \in \mathcal D_u$ and starting values $0\le \theta_k \le \theta_0; k=1,2,..,m$ for some fixed $0 \le \theta_0$ so that asymptotically as $t\to \infty$ we have $\mathbf x(t) \to \mathbf {x_{a,\theta}}$ in which I have indicated that the asymptotic values of the solution may also depend on the starting instances $\theta_k$.
I am looking for a reasonably "large" set of function $\mathbf f$ for which we can state that under these conditions the asymptotic limit is independent of the values $\theta_k \le \theta_0$ if the fixed $\theta_0$ is sufficiently small.
If the matrix $\mathbf A$ is stable having all eigenvalues with negative real part, then for the linear equation of constant coefficients $\mathbf {\dot x = Ax + Bu}$ this type of "stability", or asymptotic independence on the starting instances, is true because all the transients will decay exponentially, but I would like to know if it can be shown to hold in a non-linear case as well. A simple perturbation scheme on the excitation will not work because the amplitudes can be arbitrarily large and I got lost in the mud of calculating perturbation via $p(t-\theta_k)\approx p(t)-p'(t)\theta_k+...$
